# Set input_html values application-wide for simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I've upgraded simple_form from 2.1.0 to 3.0.3 (yes, still pretty old) and Rails from 3.2.22 to 4.2.10, and it seems like as a result, I've lost it setting for `textarea` elements associated with a `text` column a default of `cols` being 40, and `rows` being 20. Now it doesn't seem to set any values for `cols` and `rows`.

Is it possible to configure simple_form to set cols and rows for `textarea` for `text` application-wide? Or do I have to set something like

```
<%= f.input :message, input_html: {cols: 40, rows: 20} %>
```

for every input in the application?

I tried searching the simple_form github repo, and there's only three mentions of input_html in their wiki, none of which addressed this issue.

Comment: I think the only way from their documentation is to build a [custom wrapper](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple Form** offers an easy way to [change the default behaviour (v3.0.3)](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/v3.0.3/README.md#custom-inputs) by redefining existing **Simple Form** inputs. This is done by creating a new class with the same name. For instance, if you want to set default *rows* and *cols*, you can do:

```
# app/inputs/text_input.rb
class TextInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::TextInput
  def input
    input_html_options[:cols] ||= 40
    input_html_options[:rows] ||= 20
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh! I thought SimpleForm doesn't have an API for this. Good to know! :)

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario I knew this one from experience with `formtastic` which is basically an enhanced version of `simple_form`. You traced the code down to `SimpleForm::Inputs::TextInput`, but the the check for redefined or custom inputs is made from the form builder. Before the code execution arrives in the input class. https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/6a7e58705b5a09d79791f6443e6db380d0ee8b41/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L118

Answer (score 1):

### Problem:

In Rails 4.2, setting a global default value for textarea `cols` and `rows`:

### TL;DR:

Because there seems to be no public-API from both **SimpleForm 3.0** and **Rails 4.2** to be able to set default textarea `cols` and `rows` values (see my **Debugging** below as to why), then I have come up with the following workarounds:

### Workaround 1 (tested working):

create the following file:

```
# config/initializers/text_area_extensions.rb

module TextAreaExtensions
  def render
    @options[:cols] ||= 40
    @options[:rows] ||= 20
    super
  end
end

ActionView::Helpers::Tags::TextArea.class_eval do
  prepend TextAreaExtensions
end
```

... would render any textarea -- simpleform builder or rails form builder or text_area_tag -- to have default cols and rows like the following:

```
<textarea class="text" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea>
```

***NOTE*** that this is a workaround of which is not a long-term robust solution, because this is only guaranteed to work to this specific version of `ActionView::Helpers::Tags::TextArea` class. Later Rails major or even minor versions might not work!

### Workaround 2:

Instead of "patching" `ActionView::Helpers::Tags::TextArea` above, you can also patch `SimpleForm::Inputs::TextInput` if you only want to set default cols and rows for SimpleForm forms but do not set default for Rails forms, but because I prefer Workaround 1 above and my answer is too lengthy already, so I skip. But if anyone interested to know, let me know, and I'll update this.

### Workaround 3:

Probably a better approach is to use custom method that you can call (i.e. a view helper method), that will have the default cols and rows already, instead of "patching" the gem code like Workaround 1 above. However, I was under the impression that you have a big application already that you'd want to just simply set a global code, instead of manually setting/updating all affected view files (which you even said above), and thus my Workaround 1 above.

### Debugging:

I traced the code of execution:

- [SimpleForm "text" input](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/v3.0/lib/simple_form/inputs/text_input.rb):

  ```
  module SimpleForm
    module Inputs
      class TextInput < Base
        enable :placeholder, :maxlength

        def input
          @builder.text_area(attribute_name, input_html_options)
        end
      end
    end
  end
  ```
- ... which do not suggest a public API in SimpleForm to set global-default cols and rows, and so following [`input_html_options`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/v3.0/lib/simple_form/inputs/base.rb#L75):

  ```
  # ...
  @input_html_options = html_options_for(:input, input_html_classes).tap do |o|
    o[:readonly]  = true if has_readonly?
    o[:disabled]  = true if has_disabled?
    o[:autofocus] = true if has_autofocus?
  end
  # ...
  ```
- ... also do not suggest a public API in SimpleForm for setting global cols and rows. And so following Rails' `@builder.text_area` (see code above), which led me [here](http://devdocs.io/rails~4.2/actionview/helpers/formhelper#method-i-text_area):

  ```
  def text_area(object_name, method, options = {})
    Tags::TextArea.new(object_name, method, self, options).render
  end
  ```
- of which which led me [here: for
  `TextArea.new`](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActionView%2FHelpers%2FTags%2FBase:initialize)

  ```
  def initialize(object_name, method_name, template_object, options = {})
    @object_name, @method_name = object_name.to_s.dup, method_name.to_s.dup
    @template_object = template_object

    @object_name.sub!(/\[\]$/,"") || @object_name.sub!(/\[\]\]$/,"]")
    @object = retrieve_object(options.delete(:object))
    @options = options
    @auto_index = retrieve_autoindex(Regexp.last_match.pre_match) if Regexp.last_match
  end
  ```
- ... which also has no public API to set global cols and rows, and so following [next here: for `TextArea.new.render`](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActionView%2FHelpers%2FTags%2FTextArea:render)

  ```
  def render
    options = @options.stringify_keys
    add_default_name_and_id(options)

    if size = options.delete("size")
      options["cols"], options["rows"] = size.split("x") if size.respond_to?(:split)
    end

    content_tag("textarea", options.delete("value") { value_before_type_cast(object) }, options)
  end
  ```
- ... which also do not have a public API to set global cols and rows, which left me no choice but to "patch" the code using the workaround 1 above.

### Trivia:

- I verified that you are right when you said that Rails 4 no longer sets default `cols` and `rows` values for `textarea`, because seems like `DEFAULT_TEXT_AREA_OPTIONS = { "cols" => 40, "rows" => 20 }` is only implemented until Rails version 3.2.13 as you can see [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/InstanceTag)

Comment: Sometimes I can't differentiate between simple_form functionality, and Ruby on Rails functionality, so thanks for also looking into whether it was a difference in the Rails version!

Comment: No problem at all! Glad to help! :) I was curious as well, so... haha

Comment: For those wondering about the pull requests and issues relating to this, I can see the [pull request 5366 making the change](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5366), in response to [issue 5324](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5324). It's mentioned in [simple_form issue 542](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/542) as well. They talked about mentioning it in the upgrade guide ... but it didn't happen.